# Tweepy update_profile_image : Not a remote URL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, tweepy

In Tweepy document, it said filename can not a remote URL!:

```
API.update_profile_image(filename)
Update the authenticating user’s profile image. Valid formats: GIF, JPG, or PNG

Parameters: filename – local path to image file to upload. Not a remote URL!
Return type:    User object
```

I am using GAE and it does not allow to upload an image and save on server, so I always have to copy and past the image files to my application folder and update the app. 
It is painful.

Is there any suggestion?

My code is as below:

```
import import cloudstorage as gcs
gcs_f_photourl = gcs.open(photourl,'r')
image = StringIO(gcs_f_photourl)
api.update_profile_image('IMG_102433453.jpg',image)
gcs_f_photourl.close()
```

Error:

```
image = StringIO(gcs_f_photourl)

TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not ReadBuffer
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [recent commit](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/commit/d908bf7e68c6489a5c34859d19b95de3394ddb8a) added support for arbitrary file objects to be passed in. You can pass in a file object as a `file_` keyword argument, or just as 2nd positional argument. The filename is then still needed, but is only used to determine the mimetype.

On GAE, use a `StringIO` object holding the image data for that:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

image = StringIO(imagedata)
API.update_profile_image('profile.jpg', image)
```

You need a file(-like) object that supports seeking; the response object returned by `urllib2` does not. You'll have to read all data, create a `StringIO` from that and pass that to the Tweepy method.

This change is part of Tweepy 2.3.0.

Comment: I use your suggestion and i got the error. Could you please help? I updated the code at the end of question.

Comment: @John: A cloudstorage file object *supports seek directly*. In that case you don't *need* to use a `StringIO` object, just pass the `gcs_f_photourl` object to `Tweepy`.